# Your application doesn't have SLF4J binding

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, rapidclipse

I'm working with Rapidclipse and created a project. I'm always testing my project by running the servlet on a tomcat server. It always work for me until recently. Rapidclipse hang up and i had to close it with the task manager. After i started it again i couldn't start ste servlet anymore. There is always this error message:
[image: Error]

I'm desperate! Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a rough idea, based on less information you provided.
Did you work with RC4?
If yes, did you try to run a Maven update?
 
If not, select you project root in RC4. right click, select maven and update project.
Select force update of snapshot releases.

Or, second hint: check you navigation targets.